# How do I disable and enable comboBox in WPF based on some other process?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a situation in which I have to dither combo box while some process is being completed.

This snippet is of the Combo Box XAML (ItemSearchView.XAML)..

```xml
    <StackPanel Margin="2.5">
        <Label Content="{x:Static local:StringResources.LBL_FILL_LOC}" Target=" 
        {Binding ElementName=CboFillLoc}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="CboFillLoc" IsEnabled="{Binding IsComboEnabled}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding Locations}" SelectedItem="{Binding 
         SelectedLocation, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="2.5"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

This is the method where combo box need to dithered at the beginning and needs to be enabled at the end.

```
    private async void FetchItems()
    {
        try
        {
             do something
        }
        catch
        {
    
        }
        finally
        {
    
        }
    
    }
```

The purpose for this is that whenever a user is searching for the items manually, I have to restrict the user to perform other processes until all the items are loaded properly.

I am not able to achieve this since I am very new to WPF.
Any suggestions or help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Set the `IsEnabled` property of the `ComboBox` itself or a source property to`false` just before you start the long-running process and then set it back to `true` in a `finally` block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope I understood you issue correctly. You could declare a boolean property and bind it to `IsEnabled` Property of the ComboBox.

For example,in your ViewModel

```
private bool _isComboEnabled;
public bool IsComboEnabled
{
  get=>_isComboEnabled;
  set
  {
    if(_isComboEnabled==value) return;
    _isComboEnabled = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

In Xaml, you could now

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboFillLoc" IsEnabled={Binding IsComboEnabled}.../>
```

Now each time you want to invoke the `SearchItemManually` method, you could ensure the ComboEnabled flag is turned off and turn it on again at the end of the method.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Now when the combo box is enabled at the end of the process, the focus gets lost from the combo box. Should I set GotFocus = true to regain the focus? Or are there some better attribute for focus?

Comment: can you suggest me some ideas on how to get the focus back to combo box after it gets enabled? I tried Focusable and gotFocus but apparently it is not working.

Comment: There is a method called .Focus() which you need to call. GotFocus is an event which is triggered when you recieve focus

Comment: Hi , I could not find any .Focus() for combobox. There is no code behind. Am I missing something here? Please guide me. –